# Getting sum in xsl rather than creating two tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I want to get the sum of `INCENTIVEAMOUNT` inside  the `MORTGAGEINCENTIVE` tag, rather than creating two different tags.

```
<xsl:for-each select="APPLICATIONFACTFIND/QUOTATION/MORTGAGESUBQUOTE/MORTGAGEINCENTIVE">
    <xsl:element name="MORTGAGEINCENTIVE">
        <xsl:attribute name="MORTGAGEINCENTIVE">
            <xsl:value-of select="@INCENTIVEAMOUNT"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How does your input XML look? I am not sure how selecting an attribute `@INCENTIVEAMOUNT` of an element could generate several values you could sum. If you have several `MORTGAGEINCENTIVE` and want to sum all their `@INCENTIVEAMOUNT` attributes then using `sum(MORTGAGEINCENTIVE/@INCENTIVEAMOUNT)` in the context of the parent element would do.

Comment: The xml will be like <MORTGAGEINCENTIVE MORTGAGEINCENTIVE=\"200\" /><MORTGAGEINCENTIVE MORTGAGEINCENTIVE=\"5000\" />

Comment: Thanks, it worked.